# Не работает функция получения данных с API

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Есть функция в react-native для получения данных с сервера. Но, после строчки `const {data, headers} = await axios.get(url);` ничего не работает, не вызывается `console.log()` и не выполняется любой другой код. Функция запускается в в хуке `componentDidMount`, но даже если запустить по другому, все равно ничего не работает. В чем может быть проблема?

```
_getData = async page => {
  const url = `https://exmaple.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=${page}`;
  this.setState({loading: true});
  try {
    const {data, headers} = await axios.get(url);
    let posts = [...this.state.data, ...data];
    let total = headers['x-wp-totalpages'];
    this.setState({total: total, loading: false, data: posts});
  } catch (error) {
    this.setState({loading: false});
    alert('Error in getting data from the server');
  }
};
```

P.S Строчка `this.setState({loading: true});` не работает если функция вызывается через `componentDidMount`, как это исправить?

P.P.S Версия React Native 0.62, то есть последняя.

UPD. Весь код после `axios.get(url)` не выполняется

```
_getData = page => {
  const url = `https://example.com/json/${page}`;
  this.setState({loading: true});
  axios.get(url)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      let posts = [...this.state.data, ...response.data];
      this.setState({loading: false, data: posts});
    })
    .catch(e => {
      this.setState({loading: false});
      alert(`Error in getting data from the server. Error ${e}`);
    });
};
```

Comment: Убирайте `async|await` и используйте `then` для `get` запроса, на дворе 2020 год, синхронщина сейчас не модна. Не вижу в коде вообще `console.log`, с чему ему срабатывать, если его нет? Переписывайте метод, после этого можно будет двигаться дальше. Какие ошибки возникают, отправляется ли запрос? Больше деталей, и тогда станет чуточку понятнее как можно вам помочь.

Comment: @DenisBubnov Даже если поменял на then, не работает (добавил новый метод в вопрос)

Comment: Что значит код не выполняется? Какие ошибки? Хоть что-то? Уходит ли запрос? Что происходит в режиме отладки?

Comment: @DenisBubnov Ошибок нет, запрос не уходит, в режиме отладки тишина

Comment: Мистика какая-то. Давайте тогда попробуем получить данные через `fetch`, убирайте `axios.get`. Только сделайте цепочтку из двух `then`, первым будет `.then(response => response.json())`, а второй так и останется ваш `then`.

Comment: @DenisBubnov нет, ни в какую, ничего не работает, ставил функцию на кнопку, но при нажимании ничего, никакой запрос не идет. Ставил функцию пример с документации, но и она не работает.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106272/discussion-between-denis-bubnov-and-david-amerov).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это, скорее всего как-то глюк, так как вопрос решился удалением и создание нового эмулятора Android.

Comment: @Sevastopol' я и есть автор, наверное просто удалю вопрос